# How does the IMDB search work so fast?

Tags: search, optimization, scalability, imdb

There is a search box in header navigation bar (http://www.imdb.com/) and when I type 2 (or 3) letters fast, 
for less than half a second, I can see 6 results coming out!!??

Does anyone have any idea how can one search a large amount of data and get the result with a picture. :)

Are the data read from RAM ?

If you don't know for IMDB, this question is about quick search with a large number of data in general (IMDB is just very fast search I found so far), if anyone has any experience with this, it would be of great help to tell me the best way to do such a thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know much about, but from my investigation, they do the calculations on a different server. further more, they are all precompile as "json" files.

if you go to: "http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/a/all.json" all the suggestions for the query "all" (the a in the /a/all is the first letter of the query, so for "hello" it would be /h/hello.json)

Comment: I tried the URLs you provided but I always get an "AccessDenied" XML response.

Comment: I forgot to add a ".json" to the end, so the real URL is http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/a/all.json sorry about that. It takes around 58ms for each queury to that server. and they can not do spaces.

Comment: First of all, I am sorry for the late reply. Good job Delusional Logic, I think this is the answer :) thanks for your replies.

Comment: i doubt they are precompiling all of those files for every possible combination they are more likely using a cache solution that keep popular search terms ready for use likely something similar to memcache in .net  although i dont know for sure what they are using on their servers at imdb

Answer (score 0):

Im just guessing, but I'm suspicious the imdb apps (iPhone, iPad) use some kind of offline (local) search initially. I'm going to look into it...

Comment: It would be great!  Thanks for the interest in this. 
I am finishing the similar search on my web.
if it  work's as fast as IMDB's search, I will write that how I did it...